# How to rotate multiple objects properly in Java?

Tags: java, graphics, rotation, box2d, jbox2d

I have an Arraylist with objects that contains the position and rotation of an object which i want to draw on screen using Graphics2D.

```
public void render(Graphics g1) {
Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) g1;
g.setColor(Color.white);
for(PhysicObject object : entities) {

if (object.getBody().getType() == BodyType.DYNAMIC) {
            Vec2 position = object.getBody().getPosition().mul(30);
            g.translate(position.x, position.y);
            g.rotate(object.getBody().getAngle());
            g.fillRect((int)-(object.width), (int)-(object.height), (int)(object.width*2), (int)(object.height*2));
        }
    }

}
```

The first object always rotates correct, but the following rotate around the first one and not around themselves.

Hope someone can help me, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To rotate each object independently you have to undo the translation and rotation of the first object. So the simplest way is to use an AffineTransform to "combine" the two transformations and undo them easier. e.g.

```
    AffineTransform t = new AffineTransform();
    t.translate(position.x, position.y);        
    t.rotate(object.getBody().getAngle());
    g.transform(t);
    g.fillRect((int)-(object.width), (int)-(object.height), (int)(object.width*2), (int)(object.height*2));
    try{
        g.transform(t.createInverse());
    }catch(NoninvertibleTransformException e){
        //...
    }
```

The createInverse() creates the "opposite" transformation and returns the Graphics space to its original state. Then the next transformation should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

When you `translate` and `rotate` this permanently affects your graphics object.  Be sure to translate and rotate bask to the original origin and orientation after the `fillRect` call.

```
g.translate(-position.x, -position.y);
g.rotate(-object.getBody().getAngle());
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the Graphics contexts rotation method, instead try using an [AffineTransformation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html).

You will need to reset the transform on each loop.

What would be better is to take advantage of the shapes API and transform the shape instead